# Gentle way of parsing date strings without eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following strings:

```
24 hours
7 days
45 days
2 seconds
5 years
```

etc. All of those represent rails calls, like `24.hours`, `7.days`, `45.days` which always return `Integer`.

I can easily parse these strings with `eval` (replacing space with dot first).

I also can write some complicated parser that will lookup for `years` or `year` and replace it with amount of seconds.

But is there any more gentle way to parse these strings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is *gentler*, but here's an approach (with very little error checking right now):

```
def parse_time_span(value)
  acceptable_time_units = ["minute", "second", "week", "day", "hour", "month", "year"]
  value.match /([0-9]+) (.*)/
  return nil unless $1 && $2
  return nil unless acceptable_time_units.include?($2) || acceptable_time_units.collect{|x| x.pluralize}.include?($2)
  $1.to_i.send $2.to_sym
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I found this one has security issue, for example "1 byebug" or "1 pry" will prevent thread from being executed.

Comment: @RomanPushkin I updated to remove the security issue by focusing on the known time units.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, gives "undefined local variable or method `testval'" error.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [timespan](https://rubygems.org/gems/timespan) gem before, and the parsing is based on [Spanner](https://rubygems.org/gems/spanner/versions/0.0.2).

```
require 'spanner'
Spanner.parse("24 hours") #=> 86400
Spanner.parse("5 years") #=> 157784630
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it's little bit different from what Rails thinks. For example, in Rails "1.year" returns 31_557_600 seconds, but spanner returns 31_556_926. Maybe it's OK, but I'd really stick to what Rails thinks it is.